# How can I cancel my Pageflakes account?

Tags: account-management

Does anybody know how can I cancel a [Pageflakes](http://www.pageflakes.com/) account?

Answer (score 3):

Just [send them an email](http://forums.pageflakes.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=76#300):

> If you decide that you don't need your Pageflakes account anymore, and you're sure you won't want your username in the future, simply e-mail your request to cancel your account to `accounts@pageflakes.com`. Remember to send the request from the e-mail address you used to register your Pageflakes account.

Comment: Sorry, we were unable to deliver your message to the following address.

<accounts@pageflakes.com>:
Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 <accounts@pageflakes.com>: Relay access denied. [RCPT_TO]

Comment: Well, the site doesn't seem to be changed much in the last years, so I don't think there is a possibility to do anything. http://company.pageflakes.com/contact doesn't list an email address.

Comment: I sent them an email to `info@pageflakes.com` that didn't bounced back, but I had no answer yet.